# Find element from subsets with priority assigned to each subset and within subsets

Tags: algorithm, sorting, subset, dynamic-programming, weighted

S1...S5 are web pages
S1>S2>S3>S4>S5 on web pages priority.

A1..A4 are product titles
For each web page product title priority is in the order of the definition.
For S1, A1>A2>A3 on product title priority.
product title priority is only related to a particular webpage

We need top 3 web pages and corresponding product title that are unique and of highest priority.

Input:
{S1: {A1, A2, A3}, S2: {A1, A3}, S3: {A1, A2}, S4 {A4}, S5 {A1, A4}}

Expected output:
S1: A1
S2: A3
S3: A2

Input:
{S1: {A1, A2, A3}, S2: {A1, A4}, S3: {A1,A4, A5}, S4: {A6}
Expected output:
S1:A1
S2:A4
S3:A5

Input:
{S1: {A1, A2, A3}, S2: {A1, A3}, S3: {A3}}

Output:
S1:A2
S2:A1
S3:A3

Input:
{S1: {A1, A2, A3}, S2: {A3}, S3: {A3}, S4: {A4}}

Output:
S1:A1
S2:A3
S4:A4

Comment: Is the order/priority predefined, or determined at runtime?

Comment: It is Predefined